# How to filter scripts by name in Chrome's Developer Tool "Scripts" Tab

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Some sites have many scripts. For example [orionhub](http://orionhub.org).
In such a case Chrome's Developer Tools become a little bit confusing (See Picture).
Is there a way to filter the shown scripts, for example by name?

[image: many scripts on a single website]

**edit:** I found that when I am in the "Scripts" Context I can start typing and the first script matching the word I typed so far will be selected.

[image: incremental search select]

That's OK, though it would be even more helpful if that feature would support matching sub strings and wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing Ctrl/Cmd+O for an "Open Resource" dialog. It allows to quickly search file by name and supports camel case search (type yAS for yetAnotherScript).
You can see other useful shortcuts by pressing '?' in Developer Tools.

Comment: Yes, I know that shortcut. Since I haven't read anything else about this topic I assume that there currently is now other way to filter scripts. I'm not saying I'm disappointed with what chrome devtools gives me, I just think a wildcard search would greatly improve the usefulness of the search functionality.